# Storing Timestamp as Long in JDBC.. good or bad?

Tags: java, sql, datetime, jdbc

I am considering using `long` data type to store a time stamp generated via `System.currentTimeMillis`.

I want to store this value as a `BIGINT` in a relational database. 
Is this a good idea?

My main goal is to keep the DBMS-independent.. So I can move to MySQL or H2 without changing my code, and secondly make it timezone-independent.

If this is a bad idea, what is a better way?

Comment: `System.currentTimeMillis` is timezone-independent.  I don't see any problems, other than whether or not it is required to convert it to a `BIGINT` or not.

Comment: You might be DBMS independent when storing the value, but you will not be DBMS independent when you want to apply conditions in pure SQL based on real dates because the conversion of a timestamp literal (such as `timestamp '2014-09-07 14:24:00'`) will be highly DBMS dependent. If you never, ever, under no circumstance access the database outside of your application you might get away with that though. I would just use a `timestamp` column (or the equivalent in each DBMS) to store that value if you ever want to run reports on that database.

Comment: Another (very serious) drawback of that solution is that you can't prevent invalid dates in the databases.

Answer (score 2):

This is a fine idea and has been used successfully on many projects.

One issue you might think about is whether you want to generate the timestamp on the app server or on the database server. The issue is that your various app servers will have slightly different ideas about what time it is - if you want time-order consistency across the whole application, you might decide to use the database as the single source of truth on your timestamps. It depends on how your timestamps are used and how tolerant of time-order noise your application is.

Of course, it seems like each database vendor has a different function to get the equivalent of `System.currentTimeMillis`, which clearly violates one of your state goals.

Comment: I will use Java to generate the time and never rely on the DBMS for the time.

Comment: That works and is easy to implement. Just remember that if you are inserting/updating the DB from multiple servers that sorting by timestamp will generally not give you back the records in the order they were inserted. For many applications, this is not a problem.

Answer (score 2):

I would not store UTC as BIGINT. You will not be able to use the column in any meaningful way with SQL expressions. A TIMESTAMP column is portable if you import/export in ISO format.